# pip install wheel on windows when multiple python versions

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I am running python3 on windows, and have 2 python3 versions installed (3.4 and 3.5). This is necessary from some reasons. Python 3.4 seems to be the default one and is located in c:/python34/... while 3.5 is located in c:/Users/u/AppData/...

When trying to do:

```
pip install C:\Users\YOANN\Downloads\numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

or

```
pip3 install C:\Users\YOANN\Downloads\numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

I receive the error:

```
numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I'm pretty sure it's because it is trying to install it on the 3.4 version instead of 3.5 hence the version mismatch, but I can't find a workaround...

Any idea?

Comment: What is your `path` environment variable set to?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run it with the full path to pip and it should work.

```
c:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-64\Scripts\pip.exe install C:\Users\YOANN\Downloads\numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Check the first part, the `c:\Users\u` should be where you have installed your python3.5

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but [Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) may be your best friend.

Comment: That did the trick. Also using pip3.5 was a solution. thanks!

Comment: You can also use `py.exe` instead of `python.exe`.  Supply the desired Python version to `py.exe`.  Example: `py.exe -3.5 -m pip install numpy-1.12.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`.